# Jquery function not work with php echoing code

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new to php.
I want to use jquery to delete a table row from php echoing code, but it doesn't work.
Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test insert</title>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.del').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post('data.php',{action: "show"},function(res){       
            $('#result').hide().html(res).fadeIn('slow');   
        });     
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Show Data</h2>
   <button id="show">Show</button>
   <p>Result:</p>
   <div id="result"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
//connect to db
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root');
$db = mysql_select_db('test');
//if show key is pressed show records
if($_POST['action'] == 'show'){
    $sql   = "select * from customer order by Firstname";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Keynumber</th>
    <th>Number2</th><th>Number3</th><th>Option</th><th><button class='del' >delete</button></th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<tr><td>$row[firstname]</td><td>$row[lastname]</td><td class='key'>$row[keynumber]</td>
        <td>$row[number2]</td><td>$row[number3]</td><td><button class='del' >delete</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

When I press the 'delete' button, it doesn't work.
I don't know why it doesn't work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is loaded dynamically when the show button is clicked. If so, you need to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`, and .on()'s [delegated event syntax](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Change your delete button code to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: +1, although going up to `$('#result')` may be enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected ur code just check it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.del').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post(
         url:'data.php',
         data:{action: "show"},
         type:'POST',
         function(res){       
            $('#result').hide().html(res).fadeIn('slow');   
        });     
    });
});

</script>
```